# How to track razor ajax form with pace.js

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor, pace

I'm trying to learn how to use pace.js with my Razor ajax form. The form returns a Partial View. According to their documentation, there is no need for configuration as it [monitors all ajax requests](http://github.hubspot.com/pace/#collectors) (longer than 500ms). I have the following ajax form:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("MyAction", null,
new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "POST", // HttpPost
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, 
    UpdateTargetId = "myDiv", 
    OnBegin = "myBeginFunction()",
    OnSuccess = "mySuccessFunction(data.msgType, data.msg)",
    OnFailure = "myFailFunction('Error', error)",
    OnComplete = "myCompleteFunction()"
}, new { @class = "form-inline" }))
{
   //...
}
```

On `myBeginFunction()` I added `Pace.restart()`

```
function myBeginFunction()
{
   //...
   Pace.restart();
   //...
}
```

Unfortnately, load bar is not in sync with the form as the load bar completes long before the form finishes submitting. I have 2 questions

1. Is there anything special I need to do to make it track an Razor ajax form?
2. If if I need to track the form manually, how would I do so? According to the [documentation](http://github.hubspot.com/pace/#tracking), I can track like this, `Pace.track(function(){ $.ajax(...)});`, but I'm not sure how to do this with razor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I wasn't able to use pace (which would have been great since there's minimal configuration) I was able to resolve the issue using a plugin called [NProgress](http://ricostacruz.com/nprogress/). This essentially performs the same behavior but doesn't automatically perform DOM tracking as [Pace](http://github.hubspot.com/pace/#configuration) does. Therefore, I have to start and start the function manually. The JavaScript below does so with the following:

```
function myBeginFunction()
{
   //...
   NProgress.start();
   //...
}

function myCompleteFunction()
{
   //...
   NProgress.done();
   //...
}
```

Because of the nature of how NProgress works, the bar will increment but never complete until I call `NProgress.done();`

Answer (score 1):

remove pace.restart from your ajax begin function. Add this to your Page.

```
<script>
    paceOptions = {
        restartOnPushState: true,
        ajax: true,
        document: true,
        restartOnRequestAfter: true
    }
</script>
```

Comment: It doesn't work. The Ajax form returns a partial view. I'm not sure if this affects it?

Comment: ir effects every DOM activity. doesn't matter ajax or document load.

Comment: Ok thanks. Though I still wasn't able to get it to work, I found an alternative solution with the answer I posted above.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the [following link did work for me](https://github.com/HubSpot/pace/issues/110)

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function() { Pace.restart(); });
```